# Passing a block with a method to an association acts as a filter?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Consider the following models and associations.

*user.rb*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :posts
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :favorite_posts, through: :favorites, source: :post do
    def by_other_user
        where(user: self)
    end
  end
end
```

*favorite.rb*

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

*post.rb*

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Doing something like `User.find(1).favorite_posts.by_other_user` will make the following DB query:

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" 
INNER JOIN "favorites" ON "posts"."id" = "favorites"."post_id"
WHERE "favorites"."user_id" = 1 
AND "posts"."user_id" IN (
    SELECT "posts"."id" FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "favorites" ON "posts"."id" = "favorites"."post_id" WHERE "favorites"."user_id" = 1
)
```

Where does the subquery come from? Also why is `self` a collection of `Post` objects rather than the `User` object with id 1?

I realize the association is not working as intended but I don't understand the underlying query.

Last but not least, I think this association could be refactored into something like the following. But I'd appreciate any feedback on that as well.

```
has_many :favorite_posts, -> { distinct }, through: :favorites, source: :post

def favorite_posts_by_someone_else
  favorite_posts.includes(:user).where.not(posts: { user: self })
end
```

which results in the following query:

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "favorites" ON "posts"."id" = "favorites"."post_id"
WHERE "favorites"."user_id" = 1 
AND "posts"."user_id" != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that the `by_other_users` method is an extension of the `has_many` association therefore an extension of `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not your `ApplicationRecord`. That's why you can call it using `User.find(1).favorite_posts.by_other_user` and not `User.find(1).by_other_user`.

Thats why `self` is a collection of `Post` since it's like you would have called `self = User.find(1).favorite_posts`. Now we need to figure out where the query comes from.

You are effectively calling `User.find(1).favorite_posts.where(user: User.find(1).favorite_posts)` and if you look closely you will find the outer query and the subquery quite similar except for the subquery only selects `id` from `posts`.

This is caused by you providing the subquery to a filter not by a column but to a filter by an association `user`. There it expects to get a collection which would be able to return user's primary_key and since `Post` and `User` both have primary key `id`, it selects `posts.id`.

As to your last question about refactoring I think you are onto something but unless you need it for something else you don't have to include `User` to the query. I would include only the `Favorite` and filter by `favorites.user_id`.

It may be possible to write it as a second `has_many` definition with a scope which would be more up to Rails convention. However your code is perfectly readable and the resulting query would be the same, therefore I wouldn't insist on the `has_many` way if it was my project.